# xml object in String - how can i serialize it so it could stay in string

Tags: java, serialization, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am currently doing a project related to Amazon Cloud Computing. I am programming in Java.

I need to pass a message (`String` containing xml data) and I need to serialize it before putting it to the sqs queue.

Is there any way I could serialize it and keep it in string format? I cannot pass the message in any other format such as `InputStream`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
I like [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).
There is methods to convert XML to String. For Example [String: outputString()](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/output/XMLOutputter.html#outputString%28org.jdom.Document%29)